# Pytorch Training Fails on GPU, but not CPU

Tags: pytorch, object-detection

I am training YOLOv5 for object detection, I have generated some data and trained it successfully. I have recently genrated some new data using the same approach I used for the previous data and training with it now produces the following error:

> CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be
> asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace
> below might be incorrect. For debugging consider passing
> CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1

I have run the training without the GPU as it suggests and an error never appears. I'm completely lost on how to debug this. Adding image augmentation makes the error appear sooner and it seems to trip around the loss calculation which suggests there might be a problem with the data label, but in that case why doesn't it error when I'm using the CPU?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"`, then `import torch`.
This could provide a lot of info.